# Чи може основа слова = інфінітиву?

Tags: дієслова, морфологія

Знаю, що **основа слова** - це частина без закінчення. Про це читаємо навіть у [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0).

**[Інфінітив](http://bibliograph.com.ua/russkiy-yazik-2/153.htm)** - це початкова форма дієслова, яка називає дію, стан і т.д. безвідносно до особи, часу, способу, тобто сам по собі інфінітив не володіє категоріями особи, часу, способу.

Виникає питання, чи може основа слова дорівнювати інфінітиву? Наприклад, у словах казати, робити, говорити чи подібних.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оскільки в інфінітивах **–ти(-ть)** – це [суфікси](http://zno.academia.in.ua/mod/book/tool/print/index.php?id=1372) (*НЕ закінчення*), то  в цьому випадку *основа слова = ціле слово*. Незмінювані повнозначні слова складаються лише з основи, що назвивається [чистою](http://pidruchniki.com/1263111340544/dokumentoznavstvo/budova_slova): восени, додому. Чисту основу мають:
1) незмінювані іменники: бюро, таксі, депо;
**2) інфінітив: перемагати, активізувати**;
3) дієприслівники: танцюючи, малюючи, пишучи;
4) прислівники: швидко, тут, там.

Отже, в словах (казати, робити, говорити) **основа (чиста) = ціле слово,** бо це *інфінітиви*.